# Cygwin -- installing `tcl-devel` packages does not provide header files

Tags: cygwin

I have some makefile that is used to compile a program. During compilation I get an error:

```
In file included from kernel/driver.cc:20:
./kernel/yosys.h:81:12: fatal error: tcl.h: No such file or directory
   81 | #  include <tcl.h>
      |            ^~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Makefile:696: kernel/driver.o] Error 1
```

Then I rerun Cygwin setup application and install new package `tcl-devel`. I restart the Cygwin terminal and try again. The same error pops up. I don't understand! Why aren't headers found?

My `tcl` and `tcl-devel` are both of version `8.6.11-1`.

Comment: I already found the solution! I had to also install `mingw64-x86_64-tcl` (same version).

Comment: than you are not compiling a Cygwin package but a Mingw64 one

Comment: I don't understand. Could you please elaborate?